# Code for Discord.js bot responds with error "TypeError:"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm testing sending embed messages for a Discord Bot using **Discord.js** which is basically a **node.js** module used to interact with Discord's API. This is the code i'm using for the bot to send the embed message:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("This is your title, it can hold 256 characters")
    .setAuthor("Author Name", "https://i.imgur.com/lm8s41J.png")
    .setColor(0x00AE86)
    .setDescription("This is the main body of text, it can hold 2048 characters.")
    .setFooter("This is the footer text, it can hold 2048 characters", "http://i.imgur.com/w1vhFSR.png")
    .setImage("http://i.imgur.com/yVpymuV.png")
    .setThumbnail("http://i.imgur.com/p2qNFag.png")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setURL("https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/indev/class/RichEmbed")
    .addField("This is a field title, it can hold 256 characters",
        "This is a field value, it can hold 1024 characters.")
    .addField("Inline Field", "They can also be inline.", true)
    .addBlankField(true)
    .addField("Inline Field 3", "You can have a maximum of 25 fields.", true);

  message.channel.send({embed});
```

When I run the code I get this error in the Visual Studio Code IDE:

> TypeError: (intermediate
>   value).setTitle(...).setAuthor(...).setColor(...).setDescription(...).setFooter(...).setImage(...).setThumbnail(...).setTimestamp(...).setURL(...).addField(...).addField(...).addBlankField
>   is not a function

Answer (score 6):

There is not `addBlankField()` function in `MessageEmbed` class when you look at [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed), check your `discord.js` version.

As of v12.0.0 they changed `RichEmbed` to `MessageEmbed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a blank field in another way, because `.addBlankField()` isn't supported in discord.js v12. You can write this:

```
.addField("** **", "** **")
```

This will add a field with an almost empty title and description (They both contain one space after you sent the embed)

Comment: Not sure if that will work either, you can do `.addField('\u200B', '\u200B');` which would do the trick

Comment: @NotTrixxie `** **` would work. I use this trick all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    client.login('Your bot\'s token here');
    client.on('ready', () => console.log('I\'m ready !');
    client.on('message', message => {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("This is your title, it can hold 256 characters")
            .setAuthor("Author Name", "https://i.imgur.com/lm8s41J.png")
            .setColor('WHITE')
            .setDescription("This is the main body of text, it can hold 2048 characters.")
            .setFooter("This is the footer text, it can hold 2048 characters", "http://i.imgur.com/w1vhFSR.png")
            .setImage("http://i.imgur.com/yVpymuV.png")
            .setThumbnail("http://i.imgur.com/p2qNFag.png")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setURL("https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/indev/class/RichEmbed")
            .addField("This is a field title, it can hold 256 characters",
        "This is a field value, it can hold 1024 characters.")
            .addField("Inline Field", "They can also be inline.", true)
            .addField("Inline Field 3", "You can have a maximum of 25 fields.", true);

  message.channel.send(embed);
```

If that doesn't work, I would suggest checking the official documentation clicking [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)

Answer (score 0):

`.addField('\u200B', '\u200B');`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).